# Cleanly updating the fields of a deftype'd class

Tags: clojure, deftype

I'm using `deftype` for the first time because I'm writing a priority queue, and `defrecord` is interfering with implementing `ISeq`.

To avoid needing to ["deconstruct" the class, alter a field, and "reconstruct" it via explicit calls to it's constructor constantly](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/IsbmxAGEVd0/ccJGLxO4hRcJ), I found myself needing to write `update`-like functions for each field that I need to `alter`:

```
(deftype Priority-Queue [root size priority-comparator])

(defn- alter-size [^Priority-Queue queue, f]
  (->Priority-Queue (.root queue) (f (.size queue)) (.priority_comparator queue)))

(defn- alter-root [^Priority-Queue queue, f]
  (->Priority-Queue (f (.root queue)) (.size queue) (.priority_comparator queue)))
```

Of course, I could write a function to allow for a syntax closer to `update`, but the need for this at all seems like a smell.

Is this the typical way to alter non-records? I've extracted as much as I can elsewhere, so the number of times that I need to actually alter the queue itself is limited to a few places, but it still feels bulky. Is the only clean solution to write a function/macro similar to [Scala's `copy` for case classes](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-case-class-copy-method-example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would propose to make up some macro for that.. 
i ended up with this one:

```
(defmacro attach-updater [deftype-form]
  (let [T (second deftype-form)
        argnames (nth deftype-form 2)
        self (gensym "self")
        k (gensym "k")
        f (gensym "f")
        args (gensym "args")]
    `(do ~deftype-form
         (defn ~(symbol (str "update-" T))
           ^{:tag ~T} [^{:tag ~T} ~self ~k ~f & ~args]
           (new ~T ~@(map (fn [arg]
                            (let [k-arg (keyword arg)]
                              `(if (= ~k ~k-arg)
                                 (apply ~f (. ~self ~arg) ~args)
                                 (. ~self ~arg))))
                          argnames))))))
```

it just processes arg list of the deftype form, and creates the function `update-%TypeName%`, that has a similar semantics to simple `update`, using keyword variant of field name, and returns a clone of object, with altered field.

quick example:

```
(attach-updater
 (deftype MyType [a b c]))
```

which expands to the following:

```
(do
  (deftype MyType [a b c])
  (defn update-MyType [self14653 k14654 f14655 & args14656]
    (new
      MyType
      (if (= k14654 :a)
        (apply f14655 (. self14653 a) args14656)
        (. self14653 a))
      (if (= k14654 :b)
        (apply f14655 (. self14653 b) args14656)
        (. self14653 b))
      (if (= k14654 :c)
        (apply f14655 (. self14653 c) args14656)
        (. self14653 c)))))
```

and can be used like this:

```
(-> (MyType. 1 2 3)
    (update-MyType :a inc)
    (update-MyType :b + 10 20 30)
    ((fn [item] [(.a item) (.b item) (.c item)])))
;;=> [2 62 3]

(attach-updater
  (deftype SomeType [data]))

(-> (SomeType. {:a 10 :b 20})
    (update-SomeType :data assoc :x 1 :y 2 :z 3)
    (.data))
;;=> {:a 10, :b 20, :x 1, :y 2, :z 3}
```

you could also avoid generating `update-%TypeName%` function for every type, using protocol (say `Reconstruct`) and auto implementing it in macro, but this would make you lose the possibility to use varargs, since they are unsupported for protocol functions (e.g. you won't be able to do this: `(update-SomeType :data assoc :a 10 :b 20 :c 30)` )

**UPDATE**

there is also one way i can think of to avoid the use of macro here at all. Though it is cheaty one (since it uses the metadata of `->Type` constructor), and also probably slow (since it also uses reflection). But still it works:

```
(defn make-updater [T constructor-fn]
  (let [arg-names (-> constructor-fn meta :arglists first)]
    (fn [self k f & args]
      (apply constructor-fn
             (map (fn [arg-name]
                    (let [v (-> T (.getField (name arg-name)) (.get self))]
                      (if (= (keyword (name arg-name))
                             k)
                        (apply f v args)
                        v)))
                  arg-names)))))
```

and it can be used like this:

```
user> (deftype TypeX [a b c])
;;=> user.TypeX

user> (def upd-typex (make-updater TypeX #'->TypeX))
;;=> #'user/upd-typex

user> (-> (TypeX. 1 2 3)
          (upd-typex :a inc)
          (upd-typex :b + 10 20 30)
          (#(vector (.a %) (.b %) (.c %))))
;;=> [2 62 3]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is essentially what I ended up writing last night, although yours is nicer. I was hoping a custom macro wouldn't be required, but that might be too hopeful. I'm not going to accept this quite yet just to make sure, but I suspect this is the answer.

Comment: thanks! suddenly looked at the expansion, and made it simpler. Updated my answer

Comment: @Carcigenicate got one more solution, but the cheaty one. Updated my answer.

Comment: That's the first way I thought of. Ya, forcing reflection every time you need to do an update would likely be infeasible for most scenarios. Still interesting to see how someone else would write it though. Thanks.